# I want to send data to Azure IoT hub through Chirpstack

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, lora, lorawan

I want to send the data to Azure IoT hub through Chirpstack.
https://www.chirpstack.io
Gateway->MQTT->Chirpstack->Azure IoT Hub
It's not compulsory to use Chirpstack MQTT Forwader, we're flexible in that I just want to send data to IoT hub.

What I did so far is that I used LWN simulator for virtual gateway but it seems to not connect with Chirpstack. Any lead will be helpful here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this to send data to azure iot hub through [Chirpstack](https://www.chirpstack.io/project/guides/microsoft-azure/#add-gateway-to-iot-hub)

Answer (score 0):

- For the [Reference](https://www.chirpstack.io/project/guides/microsoft-azure/#add-gateway-to-iot-hub) we can send data to Azure IoT Hub through Chirpstack.Thanks for the comments @Sampath

**These are the below steps:**

- Create Azure IoT Hub in Azure.
  The Azure IoT Hub authentication thype must be used when connecting with the IoT Hub MQTT [interface](https://www.chirpstack.io/docs/chirpstack-gateway-bridge/integrations/azure-iot-hub.html).

[image]

- Setup message routing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- and the gate [way](https://github.com/chirpstack/chirpstack-docs/blob/master/src/chirpstack-gateway-bridge/integrations/azure-iot-hub.md) with Payload [formats](https://www.chirpstack.io/docs/chirpstack-gateway-bridge/payloads/index.html).
- For more details Refer Chirpstack and Azure IoT [architecture](https://forum.chirpstack.io/t/chirpstack-and-azure-iot-architecture/15797) .

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But as I don't have any real gateway device so I have to simulate one right?
So what should I use in that case?

Comment: As in the document stated:
Add gateway to IoT Hub
Under Explorers (IoT Hub overview) click on the option IoT Devices.
Click + Add then as Device ID enter the Gateway ID (e.g. 0102030405060708). This must be entered in lowercase as the IoT Hub Device ID is case-sensitive. You will find this value in your packet-forwarder configuration. Click Save.

So, what should I gave in the gateway id?
And also I'm using Chirpstack v4